# How do I avoid the timeout of each socket when sending an object?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, serialization

I will try to describe the problem as precise and summarized as possible:

I have to send a stream to exactly 254 possible devices "192.168.1.2-255" via TCP (sockets), since I need to be sure that the information arrives well, and do it in the shortest possible time.

- If I execute one line at a time, with a timeout of 200ms (which is very little), the process takes 51 seconds.
- If I execute each line in a different thread, it takes only one or two seconds, but 254 threads are created plus those that the program itself has, although they only last a second.

The object I want to send is something basic, this would be a similar example:

```
class Usuarios implements Serializable { 
   private int id,ip;
   private String name;

   //Constructor, Getters and Setters, etc...
}
```

**Is there a way to solve this problem and not have to wait a minute per cycle, or run more than 250 threads?**

Clarification: Perhaps the form is that, but it seems too much to execute so many threads even if it is a cycle of one second and repeats every 10.
**I already saw the java.NIO library but it does not clarify anywhere how to send serialized objects.**

From already thank you very much.

Comment: Have you heard about Executors ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)?

Comment: I saw that they run with a Runnable object. What difference does it make with a thread?

Answer (score 0):

Sending data throut sockets dont require a heavy cpu usae, instead uses a high i/o. You could achive fastest results with few threads using a async library like [netty](https://netty.io/). Also using a more compat serialization like [protocol buffer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview)  could reduce the time needed to send the data

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution was to use the ExecutorService and Runnable class in the following way:

```
//10 Threads to execute the task
ExecutorService threadpool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);        

Runnable task = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
     //Task to do with socket's
   }
};
threadpool.submit(task);
threadpool.shutdown();
```

Comment: It reduced the time from 51 seconds to 13, with 10 threads and timeout of 500ms.